# Error upon runnnig JDeveloper 10.1.3.4: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, jdeveloper

We are migrating from JDeveloper version **10.1.3.1** to **10.1.3.4**. We extracted the JDeveloper 10.1.3.4 to **C:/jdeveloper**. However, upon starting, we encountered the following error:

```
C:\jdeveloper\jdev\bin>jdev
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/DTD
        at oracle.ide.marshal.xml.Object2Dom.$init$(Object2Dom.java:1512)
        at oracle.ide.marshal.xml.Object2Dom.<init>(Object2Dom.java:107)
        at oracle.ide.marshal.xml.Object2Dom.newInstance(Object2Dom.java:121)
        at oracle.ide.config.IdeSettings.load(IdeSettings.java:366)
        at oracle.ide.IdeCore.loadIdeSettings(IdeCore.java:1304)
        at oracle.ide.IdeCore.getSettings(IdeCore.java:377)
        at oracle.ide.Ide.getSettings(Ide.java:308)
        at oracle.ide.config.ClientSetting.findOrCreate(ClientSetting.java:292)
        at oracle.ideimpl.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl$ExtensionSet.load(Exten
sionManagerImpl.java:1208)
        at oracle.ideimpl.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.isExtensionEnabled(Exte
nsionManagerImpl.java:1066)
        at javax.ide.extension.ExtensionRegistry$1.isExtensionEnabled(Unknown So
urce)
        at javax.ide.extension.spi.DependencyTree.buildTree(Unknown Source)
        at javax.ide.extension.ExtensionRegistry.loadExtensions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.ide.extension.ExtensionRegistry.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.ideimpl.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.initialize(ExtensionMan
agerImpl.java:763)
        at javax.ide.Service.getService(Unknown Source)
        at javax.ide.extension.ExtensionRegistry.getExtensionRegistry(Unknown So
urce)
        at oracle.ide.ExtensionRegistry.getOracleRegistry(ExtensionRegistry.java
:81)
        at oracle.ide.IdeCore.startupImpl(IdeCore.java:1049)
        at oracle.ide.Ide.startup(Ide.java:674)
        at oracle.ideimpl.Main.start(Main.java:49)
        at oracle.ideimpl.Main.main(Main.java:25
```

Anyone encountered the same error before?

Comment: What does your %PATH% variable look like? Is it actually trying to run "jdev" from the previous install location? Try running it like: ".\jdev" or "C:\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdev".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding a lib directory inside JDeveloper installation. For example:
*C:/JDeveloper10133/**lib***

Then I added the missing jar file (xmlparserv2.jar) inside the lib directory such as:

*C:/JDeveloper101.3.3/lib/**xmlparserv2.jar***